# Functions call works in console.log, but not on page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function

I have a question about the function call in React. I have two functions on a single onClick event, and they perfectly work in console.log, but when I add return, it returns nothing. Here is the code

```js
import React from "react";

let res;
let res2;

const Button = props => {
  if (props.emptyTemplates !== undefined) {
    res2 = props.emptyTemplates;
  }

  const myFunct = function() {
    console.log(props.click);
  };
  const myFunct1 = function() {
    if (props.class === "prod-button") {
      console.log(res2);
    }
  };

  return (
    <button
      onClick={event => {
        myFunct(event);
        myFunct1();
      }}
      className={props.class}
    >
      {/ {props.state ? "selected" : "select"} /}
      select
    </button>
  );
};

export { Button };
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where are you adding the return?

Comment: I am adding the return in myFunct and myFunct1 instead of console.log. @Clarity

Comment: I think instead of calling multiple functions on a single click, you can call a function inside another function. And the single return will work in that case.

Comment: @OpieWinston what are you trying to achieve with a return there?

Comment: I have tried that before and the same problem occurred. @RohanKumar

Comment: @OpieWinston there seems nothing which should be return to button event. What is your actual problem ?

Comment: @Clarity I am trying to add items to the array on one click and empty on other if different card is selected

Comment: @RohanKumar my problem is that both functions work when I single call them in onClick, but when I put them in wrapper function, they not working. Only when i console.log them